# How to display a custom field in LoginPartial page using MVC4 and razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, custom-fields

I have added few extra fields to my UserProfile and want to display First and Last Name fields in _LoginPartial.cshtml page. Can someone please help me.

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}


public class RegisterModel
{

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"[\w-]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+", ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid email address")]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }


    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [RegularExpression(@"[\w-]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+", ErrorMessage = "not a valid email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("([a-zA-Z0-9 .&'-]+)", ErrorMessage = "Enter only alphabets and numbers of First Name")]
    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}
```

_LoginPartial.chtml

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <text>
        <font color="white"> 
        @*Hello,</font> @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })!*@

        Hello,</font> @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })!
        @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>

        }
    </text>
}
else
{
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

Here is the website I am working on:

http://overseasindians.com.au/

Comment: Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 4):

1- first add this action to account controller:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult GetUserInfo()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var context = new BlogDBEntities();
        var id = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
        var user = context.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserId == id);
        return PartialView(user);
    }
    return PartialView();
}
```

2- create partilaview for this action: GetUserInfo.cshtml

```
@model MVCBlog.Models.UserProfile
@if (Model != null)
{
@Model.RealName
}
```

3- modify _loginPartial.cshtml as follows:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    <text>
        Hello, @Html.ActionLink(Html.Action("GetUserInfo", "Account").ToString(), "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })!
        @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
        }

    </text>
} else {
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you

```
[Datatype.Email]
[Display(Name = "User name")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Instead of what you have currently.